# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'

Tags: python

While solving a problem on Hackerrank, i am getting this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'
```

Here is the code i have written to get the runner-up score in an array of scores -

```
        from array import *
        n = int(input())
        A = array('i', [])
        
        for a in range(n):
            x = int(input())
            A.append(int(x))
        
        for i in range(0, len(A)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
                if A[i] > A[j]:
                    temp = A[i]
                    A[i] = A[j]
                    A[j] = temp
        print(A[len(A)-2])
```

Funny thing is, it works in PyCharm but not in HackerRank.

Comment: From the error, you entered `2 3 6 6 5` for one of the inputs.  That won't work as an argument to `int`.  You may only pass `int` a single integer string.  Try entering the numbers one per line.  If you want to enter more than one per line, use `split` to break them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really post a reproducible example, because merely stating that the code is run on Hackerrank is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.

**However**, it appears that your code is being called with an input of `'2 3 6 6 5'`, and if you want to append all of these numbers to the list, then you would need to change:

```
            x = int(input())
            A.append(int(x))
```

to:

```
            for x in input().split():
                A.append(int(x))
```

Your existing code will fail if the input is a string containing a space-separated list of integers. And where the input string contains just the one integer, it is unnecessarily converting it to `int` twice (the second call to `int` will simply return the value which is already an int).